# int logctl_get(): open '/dev/hwlog_switch' fail -1, 13. Permission denied

Tags: android, python

In my Huawei phone, I operate:
step1:dial *#*#2846579#*#*
step2: click Background setting
step3: click LOG setting
step4: trun on Log setting,for example , AP Log
but whenever I reboot, the LOG Settings are back to nothing enabled
has someone can help me?
when I not reboot, in android studio logcat ,log is normal.
But I use

```
logcatLogfile = open(filePath, 'w+')
logcatSubProcess = subprocess.Popen('adb shell logcat', stdout=logcatLogfile,tderr=logcatLogfile)
```

logcatLogfile is not whole log,some logs has lost

Comment: my phone's  model is  Huawei nova2

Comment: Use 'adb logcat' instead of 'adb shell logcat'

Comment: @tcardoso Thank you very much , 'adb logcat'  can resolve my problem, but I want to a filter to the log, it does not work.code is :   adb logcat | grep ******